# CSS: Triangle with a dip in the middle

Tags: css, css-shapes

I'm wanting to give [this triangle](http://jsbin.com/dusafayasu/1/edit) a dip in the middle, and I do not want any extra HTML.

```
<span class="dropdown">dropdown</span>

.dropdown:after
{
    display: inline-block;

    margin-left: 4px;

    content: '';

    border-top: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
}
```

Desired result

[image: http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/32195.png]

How may I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
.dropdown:after {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  content: "";
  top: -2px;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: 4px;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border-right: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsbin.com/huposifapu/1)

Note that there are other options too i.e. icon fonts, background images, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Using only CSS I'm not sure how to create the rounded ends on the arrow. But to create a lined arrow, you can overlay the `:before` and `:after` elements on top of each other like so:

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown:after {
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  top: 7px;
  content: '';
  border-top: 3px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-right: 3px solid transparent;
  border-left: 3px solid transparent;
  z-index: 1001;
}
.dropdown:before {
  position: absolute;
  right: -14px;
  top: 7px;
  content: '';
  border-top: 5px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<span class="dropdown">dropdown</span>
```